# object constructor or function call?

Tags: c++

```
void f(string &x);
..
f(string("hello1"));
...
f(new string("hello2"));
```

1. How does compiler know if string("hello1") is function call or constructor call?
2. What is the difference between hello1 and hello2?

Comment: The second one won't compile. The function `f()` takes a a `string` by reference and you are trying to pass a `pointer to string`.

Comment: If you name a function `string`, it won't compile. Hence it will always be a constructor.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm pressed to see how the first one will compile either, since the function expects a non-const reference and he's giving it a temporary. So.. none of this works.

Answer (score 2):

1) From the context, in general. C++ does not have context free grammar like Rust for instance. However in this special case, it is always the string construction. Also, note that it does not compile since you would pass a rvalue to a non-const refeference.

2) hello2 creates a new string object on the heap, and hello1 does not. Also, note that you cannot pass a pointer to a function expecting a reference like this. It will not simply build with msvc, gcc, cland and so forth.